# Comparing a possibly empty string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I'm trying to compare a string field from a LINQ query on a database using:

```
e.Comment.equals("Working From Home")
```

on the WHERE clause.

However, sometimes the Comment field could be empty which currently causes an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception.

Is there any way I can check if the Comment isn't empty and THEN compare to avoid the exception?

Comment: You could do "Working From Home".Equals(e.Comment) or use string.IsNullOrEmpty()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `==` instead of Equals:

```
e.Comment == "Working From Home"
```

LINQ to SQL will correctly translate this to the appropriate SQL syntax.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, didn't even think about it being so simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it should be enough to use the '==' operator instead:

```
e.Comment == "Working From Home"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Comment) && e.Comment == "Working From Home"
```

Comment: While I'm not sure .NET will understand how to translate `IsNullOrEmpty` into SQL if he is using LINQ to SQL, the `==` will do both of the jobs done by `IsnullOrEmpty`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `"Working From Home".Equals(e.Comment);` or `String.Equals(e.Comment, "Working From Home");`